# Ruby on Rails : Mismatch in External linked CSS file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a CSS file in the path : `public\stylesheets`

I have linked this external file to all pages via

```
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/ecssp.css"
```

Everything except the header and header's background is not displayed.

If the style sheet code is written within the file (Internal) , then the header and header's background is displayed.

So issue is only when I link it via external css file.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Your paths IN your css files are wrong. You may post some url(); statement in your css file to get further information.

Example:

in css: background-image: url(images/image.jpg); works in your header because it starts from / ("root"). But your stylesheets starts from /public/stylesheets, so it would look for /public/stylesheets/images/image.jpg.

Change paths in your css to absolute => url(/images/...) or real relatives => url(../images/...)